GoRouter navigating to the root or top of the stack when opening keyboard
I have implemented GoRouter in the flutter app and managed all the routes and the app flow and navigation works fine. However when I open the keyboard for any input fields like text field and form field then the app redirects to the top of the stack. I have managed the authentication so if am logged out opening keyboard rebuilds and am back to login page and if I am logged in then am again back to my homescreen. What may have caused this issue?
I have tried wrapping the material app with consumer to listen to the change but still the issue persists.
here is my code:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
      create: (_) => authService,
      child: Consumer<AuthService>(
        builder: (context, authService, _) {
          return MaterialApp.router(
            routerConfig:router(authService),
          );
        },

static GoRouter router(AuthService authService) => GoRouter(
        initialLocation: authService.isAuthenticated ? RouteNames.dashboard : RouteNames.login,
        refreshListenable: authService,
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            builder: (context, state) => authService.isAuthenticated ? const DashboardScreen() : const LoginScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: RouteNames.login,
            builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: RouteNames.register,
            builder: (context, state) => const RegisterScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: RouteNames.passwordReset,
            builder: (context, state) => const pwdRstScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: RouteNames.dashboard,
            builder: (context, state) => const DashboardScreen(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: RouteNames.firstPage.lastPathSegment(),
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return FirstPage(
                    title: title,
                    path: path,
                  );
                },
                routes:[
               //here are my nested routes]
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
         redirect: (context, state) {
          final loggedIn = authService.isAuthenticated;
          final loggingIn = state.subloc == RouteNames.login;
          if (!loggedIn && !loggingIn) return RouteNames.login;
          if (loggedIn && loggingIn) return RouteNames.dashboard;
          return null;
        },
      );
}

//singleton authservice class:
class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final AuthService _instance = AuthService._internal();

  factory AuthService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  AuthService._internal() {
    _loadFromPrefs();
  }

  bool _isAuthenticated = prefs.isAuthenticated();

  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  void _loadFromPrefs() async {
    _isAuthenticated = CorePrefs.isAuthenticated();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> setAuthenticated(bool value) async {
    if (_isAuthenticated != value) {
      _isAuthenticated = value;
      await prefs.isAuthenticated(value: value);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}

return ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => AuthService(),
  child: MyApp(),
);

//inside MyApp
//widget build...
final AuthService authService = AuthService();
return Consumer<AuthService>(
                  builder: (context, authService, child) {
                    return MaterialApp.router(...);}


You called router(authService) every AuthService state changed. It will apply new GoRouter instance and lead you to it's initialLocation. So just keep GoRouter instance somewhere base on your logic.

_isAuthenticated = CorePrefs.isAuthenticated(); will only be changed when making api requests and if I am in the same page then no api will be called while tapping on text/form field. Still the keyboard would not load and am instantly navigated to initial location. Without tapping on keyboard the app works just fine. I can smoothly navigate as expected.
